# Проблема с кодировкой на уровне БД

Tags: база-данных, mysql, sql

У меня везде UTF=8, но в Бд сохраняется всякий бред.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После соединения с БД, выполните запросы:

```
SET NAMES utf8;
SET CHARACTER SET utf8;
```